# create mysql database from variable in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, mariadb

I'm trying to write a bash script that will create a database using a variable for the new name but not having any luck with the syntax. I know almost next to nothing about bash.  Keeps telling me there's a syntax error at line 1 after I enter the db password.

**setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

db="mytest"

scl enable rh-mariadb 'mysql -u user -p -e "set @dbname=$db; \. setup_db.sql"'
```

**setup_db.sql**

```
SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE `', @dbname, '`');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREAPRE stmt;
```

If I hardcode the db name where I have $db in the bash then I receive this error:

*Unknown column 'mytest' in 'field list'*

Comment: That error doesn't come from the `CREATE DATABASE` statement. You probably have some other statement in your `setup_db.sql` file that is malformed.

Comment: You should also look at the [mysqladmin tool](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqladmin/). You can create a schema more easily.

Comment: Doesn't this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470753/create-mysql-database-and-user-in-bash-script

Comment: Or this one maybe. https://superuser.com/questions/288621/create-mysql-database-with-one-line-in-bash

Comment: Second one doesn't use a variable. I saw the first one but no it hasn't helped.

Comment: I've verified that dbname is getting created as it's seen in information_schema.USER_VARIABLES. And I've echoed 'db' before assigning it to dbname and that checks out as well. But in the sql script the variable is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the DB name in quotes in quotes, otherwise it's treated as a column name.

```
scl enable rh-mariadb 'mysql -u user -p -e "set @dbname=\"$db\"; \. setup_db.sql"'
```

Comment: That fixed the error, but the variable is being received in the sql script as empty.